# How to use ItemsControl to assign <DataGrid.Columns>?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, wpfdatagrid

i have a datagrid in a control(here:DataGridSelectorControl) and i want to create it's coulmns using ItemTemplate.actually i want to do something like this:

```
  <DataGrid  x:Name="grd" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource theSource}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridColumnItems}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

i want to know is there any way to use an ItemsControl for DataGrid.Columns??
and i want do that because i want to use this control like this:(i want to define DataGridTextColumns  whenever create an instance of this control)

```
<control:DataGridSelectorControl Grid.Row="1">
        <control:DataGridSelectorControl.DataGridColumnItems>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="نام"  Width="20"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ParentID" Width="20"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </control:DataGridSelectorControl.DataGridColumnItems>
    </control:DataGridSelectorControl>
```

and DataGridColumnItems is an atachepropery:

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty DataGridTextColumnItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DataTextColumnItems", typeof(DataGridColumn), typeof(DataGridSelectorControl));
    public DataGridColumn DataGridColumnItems
    {
        get
        {
            return (DataGridColumn)GetValue(DataGridTextColumnItemsProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DataGridTextColumnItemsProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGrid.Columns is of type ObservableCollection, try something like this:

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty DataGridTextColumnItemsProperty=DependencyProperty.Register("DataTextColumnItems", typeof(ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>), typeof(DataGridSelectorControl)))); 
    public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> DataGridColumnItems 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return (ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>)GetValue(DataGridTextColumnItemsProperty); 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            SetValue(DataGridTextColumnItemsProperty, value); 
        } 
    }

  <DataGrid  x:Name="grd" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource theSource}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Columns={Binding DataGridTextColumnItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridSelectorControl}}> 
            </DataGrid>
```